# How do I automatically enter credentials to a javascript pop up? I tried "webdriver wait" but I am getting "TimedOutException"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Edit:**    It turns out that the "**javascript popup**" wasn't actually a javascript popup. It was a "**basic authorization popup**". I solved the problem using "**AutoIt**" but Alex from SO recommended to look for **basic authorization pop-up**. Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194474/how-to-enter-the-credentials-in-a-javascript-pop-up-we-cant-pass-the-credentia).

I am trying to access webpage A but it redirects to webpage B, which then takes in the email ID and then redirects to a webpage C, which has that Javascript pop-up for entering email ID(which was previously entered) and password which will then take me to a desired webpage.

The problem is that if I am using "webdriver wait" it won't even take me to the page C where I need to enter email ID and password. If I remove the "webdriver wait " I can go to at least page C, but still I am not able to enter the ID and password!

```
driver.get("https://website.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"i0116\"]")).sendKeys("email@email.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"idSIButton9\"]")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);              //if I remove this line and below line
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());  //then only I reach to the page C 
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("email@email.com");
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("passwordofemail");
```

When the webdriver wait is there in the code I am getting this exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval).

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception? Is it the email or the password?

Comment: In console it says the line which has "Alert alert= ...." (3rd last line). When I'm removing the lines "WebdriverWait wait...." & "Alert alert=..." (4th and 5th lines from the top) then only I am able to reach the page which has dialog box/pop-up to enter both email and password