# How to enter the credentials in a Javascript pop-up? We can't pass the credentials in the link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Edit: I solved the problem by using "**AutoIt**". However as Alex said AutoIt is platform dependent I am going to try and implement it.

I have link A, where I need to enter my email Id, it then automatically redirects to link B which has a javascript pop-up which needs email id and password to redirect me to the desired page. This is what I have done till now. 
I tried passing the credentials in the link A, but it didn't work. 
Instead of going from link A to link B, I copied link B and passed the credentials along with it. I got server error.
I tried using sikuli pattern and screen class, but It said "error path cannot be found" for which I tried looking for the solution but couldn't as it got deprecated or something.

here is my code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://linkA.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"uemail\"]")).sendKeys("emailID@email.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"button\"]/div[2]/button")).click();
```

After this code I am redirected to link B, where the javascript popup actually is.Till here everything is fine.

Instead of last 3 lines I tried these things.

```
driver.get("https://emailID:password@linkA.com");
```

And

```
driver.get("https://emailID:password@linkB.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the latter is not JavaScript pop-up but basic authorization pop-up that is not under control of web driver. You need to set up a proxy that would add `Authorization` header to your requests, and assign your `username:password` pair encoded in Base64.

Here are some detail on [how to apply Browsermob Proxy library to address Basic auth issue](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization).

What you have tried so far is actually deprecated due to security reasons and no more supported is the majority of modern browsers.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info and link! I solved the problem by using "Auto It".

Comment: okay, however Auto-It is platform-dependent and efforts to integrate proxy solution is even less then to integrate AutoIt into your Java test code.

Comment: I was told by my colleagues to use Auto-It, so I tried and it worked. But I am understanding your point and I will try to implement the proxy method. Thank you!